# Denying timestamp modification on SFTP server

Tags: linux, filesystems, sftp

I have a linux SFTP server which I use to share files with other people.

There is a script that automatically find and delete files uploaded more than 10 days ago:

`find . -not -path . -mtime +10 -exec rm -frv {} \;`

I've noticed that some SFTP clients preserve *last modified* date, causing the script to delete the files sooner than expected.

For instance, if Today is 15th of December, and a client upload a file that he modified on his computer on the 1st of December, the file gets deleted immediately, instead of the 25th of December.

So, how can I deny the clients to change *last modified* attribute after the upload?

Comment: What SFTP server?

Comment: I'm using the standard openssh service with internal-sftp config directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`sftp-server`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp-server) (and the compatible `internal-sftp`) has the `-P` and `-p` switches to black/white list certain SFTP requests.

You can use them to disallow `setstat` and `fsetstat` requests:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -P setstat,fsetstat
```

Note that this will disallow also permissions (and other attributes) changes.

You can of course do this per-user (or per other criteria) using the `Match` directive.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this cleanly and you are acting "against" Unix/Linux established practices. The expected way to do your task is to use `-mtime +10 -ctime +10`, that is delete files that are older with respect to both mtime *and ctime*.

Many tools that operate files set mtime back to the past when the contents *meaningfully* changed. But the ctime ("inode change time") is an indicator that something about the file has changed: mtime or contents or permissions or other metadata.

Also warning: your script will have unintended consequences because it checks also mtime of directories and deletes whole directories. When you write to files, directory's mtime and ctime doesn't change, thus files *will* be deleted as a result of `rm -r ./that/directory`